# encode a NSString setHttpPostBody for nsurlconnection

Tags: objective-c, ios, web-services

String content = "username="+ URLEncoder.encode(username, UTF_8_TYPE);

want to do a similar in objectiveC

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *body = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"username=%@", [username stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

Comment: NSString *body = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"username=%@", [@"user3"stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]]; output: body = user3 i get the same value not encoded

Comment: it's not my fault, NSString knows which characters need escaping and which don't...

Comment: for all the value i give i get the same value as output

Comment: I understand, but I can't do anything about that, sorry.

Comment: What chars are you having trouble with?